# Convention for actions returning multiple View Types (html, json, partials)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building a website in ASP.NET MVC5. In my controllers, I have some actions that return the same data but in different formats mostly Views, partial views and Json.

For example, I would have a controller which display a list of items :

```
// some action returning a view
public ActionResult List()
{
   var model= _repository.Items.ToViewModel();
   return View(model)
}

// some action returning a partial view
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ListPartial()
{
   var model= _repository.Items.ToViewModel();
   return PartialView("_ListPartial", model)
}

// some action returning JSON
public ActionResult GetList()
{
   var model= _repository.Items.ToViewModel();
   return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How can I make a clear distinction between my actions ?
What kind of conventions should be followed to keep it clean?
Should the actions co-exist in the same controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "make a clear distinction between my actions". From a compiler perspective, the distinction between action methods will always depend on one of two things: the name of the action and the parameters that action takes. So, you could have two actions with the same name, but different parameters, or two actions with totally different names and the same or different parameters. From a developer perspective, you can add to the previous list: return value. Personally, I can look at any of the actions you have here and clearly see what they're doing based on that, i.e. the one that returns the model encoded as JSON, is obviously a JSON result.

As far as keeping things clean goes, again, that's a somewhat loaded question. What defines "clean"? Your methods look perfectly "clean" to me as-is. You've got a bit of code duplication, but I'd consider that acceptable in this scenario. All you're doing is retrieving a model in each. One could argue for leaving such duplicate code, as potentially each method could diverge over time, retrieving more or less parts of that model or including other related entities, etc.

However, if you want to remove the code duplication, you could factor that line out into an internal method on the controller, and then have each action call that internal method. That way, if you need to modify the line, you only need to do it in one place, but of course, if you need to make a modification just for one of these actions, you're back to where you were before.

Now, to should the actions co-exist in the same controller, this is a bit subjective as well. Since, they're so closely related in functionality, with just different return values, there's an easy argument for keeping them in the same controller. However, it's equally valid to suggest moving them into different controllers so, for example, you have all your JSON returning actions together. A lot of it boils down to personal preference.

Now, all that said, in this one particular scenario, since literally the only difference is the return value depending on the methodology being used to get the action, you can actually combine all of these into one action:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
   var model= _repository.Items.ToViewModel();

   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
       return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }

   if (ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
   {
       return PartialView("_ListPartial", model);
   }

   return View(model);
}
```

This is possible because your action's return value of `ActionResult`, is a base class that all of `ViewResult`, `PartialViewResult` and `JsonResult` inherit from.

Comment: I was looking for a naming convention on methods, so that humans can identify them directly from the name. But i now don't need it anymore, I didn't know that I had access to the type of request and controller action type! I will use that! Are there any scenario where this kind of check is not recommended ?

Comment: Well,  I would only use it in the narrow scenario like this,  where the only difference is the return value.  If you're going to be doing a lot of separate processing based on whether it's requested via AJAX or as a child action,  you should just use separate actions instead.

Answer (score 2):

ActionResult is an abstract class and all other result classes are derived from that.
Instead of user ActionReault for all method use derived class name. Like JsonResult, ViewResult , PartialViewResult